# Create columns by unique row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following dataset (a bit more elaborate but the below gives a good indication);

```
A   B   C
22  1  52
22  2  14
22  3  11
22  4  9
23  1  20
23  2  15
23  3  8
23  4  60
24  1  45
24  2  12
24  3  40
24  4  52
```

and I'm looking to pivot/stack or something to get the following;
(Essentially to make the unique values in 'A' the column headers and then B would be in the index)

```
  22  23  24
1 52  20  45
2 14  15  12
3 11  8   40
4 9   60  52
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: with ```pivot_table``` --> ```df.pivot_table(columns='A',index='B',values='C')```

Comment: or crosstab `pd.crosstab(df.B,df.A,df.C,aggfunc='first')`

Comment: or unstack `df.set_index(["A","B"]).unstack("A")`.

Comment: These are all really helpful, thank you!